# How to group by month and unique users in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe, df, as follows:

| date | user ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2006-02-13 | 1 |
| 2006-02-14 | 2 |
| 2006-03-02 | 1 |
| 2006-02-22 | 1 |
| 2006-03-30 | 3 |
| 2006-04-01 | 1 |
| 2006-04-02 | 2 |
| 2006-04-01 | 2 |
| 2006-04-05 | 3 |

I want to group the data by month and number of unique user's so I can get the output as:

| date | unique user's |
| --- | --- |
| February | 2 |
| March | 2 |
| April | 3 |

I have tried:
`mau = mau.groupby([mau.timestamp.dt.to_period('M'), 'userid'])`

but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nunique`:

```
mau.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M'))['user ID'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
date
2006-02-28    2
2006-03-31    2
2006-04-30    3
Freq: M, Name: user ID, dtype: int64
```